# How to fix char problems like kire\u00e7?

Tags: php, html, char

The strange encoding occurs when article includes letters like "ş, ç, ö, İ". How can I fix this ?

```
Kesme \u015fekere benzeyen, kire\u00e7 beyaz\u0131 evleriyle kar\u015f\u0131l\u0131yor BODRUM bizi..T\u0131pk\u0131, \u00e7ocuklu\u011fumuzdaki gibi.. Pencerelerdeki mavi \u00e7izgiler, denizin g\u00fcl\u00fcmsemesi adeta.. Ve denizden esen ilk r\u00fczgar bir\u00e7ok kokuyla ho\u015fgeldin diyor bize..Eski sevgililer, aile, dostluklar, an\u0131lar.. Film \u015feridi gibi ge\u00e7iyor \u00f6n\u00fcm\u00fczden
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sending this data in JSON? If so, that's standard encoding for Unicode characters, and you can simply run it through [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json-decode) to decode them.

If not, more information will be needed to help you.

Comment: I am grabbing post from https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=bodrum+castle&type=post&lang=en , I've tried json_decode but can't get it working.

Comment: Keep the quotes around the message (ie. change it so the quotes are inside the `()`). That should make it work.